# android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

In some **very rare cases**, there is a crash on this line:

> mCurrentDialogFragment.get().setArguments(bundle);

```
protected void showDateTimePickerDialog() {
        mCurrentDialogFragment = new WeakReference<AppCompatDialogFragment>(new DateTimePickerDialogFragment());
        ((DateTimePickerDialogFragment) mCurrentDialogFragment.get()).setOnDateTimeSelectedListener(
                new DateTimePickerDialogFragment.OnDateTimeSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDateTimeSet(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth,
                                              int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        ...
                });

        DateTime dt = new DateTime(mCalendarTimeLineAdapter.convertPositionToMs(
                mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));

        if (mCurrentDialogFragment != null && mCurrentDialogFragment.get() != null) {
            Pair<Boolean, SublimeOptions> optionsPair =
                    TimeUtils.getDateTimePickerOptionsForDiary(mScheduleRange,
                            new DateTime(dt), mCalendarTimeLineAdapter.getCalendarTodayPosition());

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(DateTimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_DATETIME_OPTIONS, optionsPair.second);

            // **** CRASH HERE
            mCurrentDialogFragment.get().setArguments(bundle);

            mCurrentDialogFragment.get().setStyle(android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
            mCurrentDialogFragment.get().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
        }
    }
```

How is possible? I can't understand how the reference can be null...

Do you have some explanations guys?

Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

Try to initialize your Dialoig  `mCurrentDialogFragment = null` and then assign it .